# Как сделать перенос на новую строку слова целиком?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Делаю плагин-виджет к Wordpress.
Вывожу заголовок виджета так:

```
echo $before_title . '<p>Средний прогресс пользователей</p>' . $after_title;
```

В заголовке браузер переносит текст на новую строку, разбивая слово на части:
[image: Нежелательный перенос слова]

Смотрится некрасиво. В данной ситуации вполне реально перенести на новую строку слово целиком. Оно поместиться на новой строке.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как заставить браузер переносить слово целиком, не разбивая его?

Я пробовал задавать разные значения стилей word-wrap и word-break, но это никак не влияет на данный перенос.
Вставлять между словами <br> не хочется, так как в будущем может возникнуть ситуация, что перенос не понадобиться и весь текст будет влезать в одну строку.

Comment: Пожалуйста ставьте пример вашего кода, который показывает проблему. Без специяльного кода не бывает, что слова так разбиваются.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Для того, чтобы на вопрос можно было ответить, добавьте весь относящийся к проблеме код и сообщения об ошибках в сам вопрос. [ask], [как создать краткий, завершенный и достоверный пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Возможно, этот вопрос будет помечен как [требующий правки]. После того, как вы отредактируете вопрос и добавите код, его переоткроют.

Comment: Какая в результате разметка получается?